# LaTeX3 Text/String Comparison Replacement for xstring

Tags: latex3, xstring

Trying to update my college's LaTeX thesis class (for fun while I wait for the actual degree to show up). It hasn't been touched in a few years.

Anyways, one of the commands it has is below:

```
% TODO: See if the new LaTeX3 can handle this without "xstring" package
\usepackage{xstring} % Needed for "checkboxYesNo" command
\newcommand{\checkboxYesNo}[2]{
    %% #1--Find This;  #2--Search This List
    %% Outputs a Checked or Unchecked box 
    \lowercase{\def\myList{#2}}%
    \lowercase{\def\findMe{#1}}%
    \IfSubStr{\myList}{\findMe}{\checkYes}{\checkNo}%
    % \IfSubStr{\myList}{\findMe}{Yes \findMe - \myList}{No \findMe - \myList}%
}
```

As you can see, the `TODO` note has a comment about removing the reliance on `xstring` package and I am not sure if the new LaTeX3 items can do that.

The `\checkYes` and `\checkNo` are just calls to functions that draw TikZ pictures of checked or unchecked boxes for a checklist.

EDIT: as egreg pointed out, I forgot examples (I'm sorry! the coffee hasn't kicked in yet...)

`\checkboxYesNo{t}{iar}` or `\checkboxYesNo{a}{#6}` where `#6` is a combination of the letters `tair` in any order or capitalization.

Basically the function is checking if the #2 argument contains the letter from the #1 argument. If it does, it launches into the `\checkYes` command otherwise it enters into the `\checkNo` command
`\IfSubStr{\myList}{\findMe}{\checkYes}{\checkNo}` being the item that is causing me the issue.

Edit: Add semi-MWE

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\checkboxYesNo}{vv}
{
  \prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \str_if_in:nn {ee} { TF, T, F }
  \str_if_in:eeTF { \str_foldcase:n { #2 } } { \str_foldcase:n { #1 } } {Yes} {No}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

`\checkboxYesNo{a}{abc}` produces `Yes` while `\checkboxYesNo{q}{abc}` return `No`

Comment: What do you expect to be in `#1` and `#2`? Can you add a few examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `expl3` analog of `\IfSubStr` is

```
\str_if_in:nnTF
```

but you want caseless comparison, so you need to plug in `\str_foldcase:n`. Hence you first need an `ee` variant of `\str_if_in:nnTF`:

```
\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \str_if_in:nn {ee} { TF, T, F }
```

and you can do your test with

```
\str_if_in:eeTF { \str_foldcase:n { #2 } } { \str_foldcase:n { #1 } } { \checkYes } { \checkNo }
```

(the second argument is tested for being a substring of the first argument).

Comment: Do I need to call the `expl3` package or is that included in the newest version of the base code for LaTeX?

Comment: @Nebabon Nowadays the `expl3` layer is included in the LaTeX kernel.

Comment: That's what I through but was not sure. I'm getting an error with it. I am getting an error. I _think_ this is correct
```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \checkboxYesNoMore:n #1 #2 {
    \str_if_in:eeTF { \str_foldcase:n { #2 } } { \str_foldcase:n { #1 } } { Yes } { No }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```
but I am getting an error of `Undefined control sequence. \checkboxYesNoMore`

Comment: @Nebabon *What* control sequence is undefined? Surely not `\checkboxYesNoMore`, look in the log file to find precisely.

Comment: It looks like `\checkboxYesNoMore` is the undefined one. When I comment the single call to that, it compiles correctly. When I leave that in, it fails.

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.6 \checkboxYesNoMore
                      {t}{tair}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed.
```
with ```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \checkboxYesNoMore:n #1 #2 {
  \str_if_in:eeTF { \str_foldcase:n { #2 } } { \str_foldcase:n { #1 } } { Yes } { No }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Comment: @Nebabon I see! You're defining `\checkboxYesNoMore:n`, not `\checkboxYesNoMore`.

Comment: `\checkboxYesNoMore` and `\checkboxYesNoMore:n` produce the same error. Is it possible the engine ("pdflatex") is causing the problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134720/discussion-between-nebabon-and-egreg).